# jQuery.fn.extend doesn't work (v: 1.12.4)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make my own function for jQuery, like this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    myfunc: function() {
        $(this).addClass("myfunc");
    }
});
```

However, when I call it from $("#myobj").myfunc(), it does nothing.
Can someone help me? I'm using the minified core 1.12.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `this` inside `myfunc` refers to a jQuery iterable object, so to apply any modifications you should do it using `each`. Also, custom functions must return an iterable JQuery object so it can be chained with any other jQuery method.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    myfunc: function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).addClass("myfunc");
        });
    }
});
```

More about extending the native `fn` jQuery definition can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/).